# Java MapReduce: how to store a list of LONGs in Hadoop Output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce Java program which outputs a list of numbers as String as the final output. But the number is relatively long and consumes too much space. I want to convert each number to Long and store. How can I achieve this?

Comment: On 2nd thought, I guess I have to implement a new type holding a list of LONGs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ArrayWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html) can be extended as

```
public class LongArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public LongArrayWritable() {
        super(Text.class);
    }

    public LongArrayWritable(LongWritable[] values) {
        super(LongWritable.class, values);
    }
}
```

Also, a String can be converted into [LongWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/LongWritable.html) as

```
String s = "123456";
new LongWritable((new Long(s)).longValue());
```